# Multipart form post to google app engine not working

Tags: python, google-app-engine, forms, html-post

I am trying to post a multi-part form using httplib, url is hosted on google app engine, on post it says Method not allowed, though the post using urllib2 works. Full working example is attached.

My question is what is the difference between two, why one works but not the other

1. is there a problem in my mulipart form post code?
2. or the problem is with google app engine?
3. or something else ?

---

```
import httplib
import urllib2, urllib

# multipart form post using httplib fails, saying
# 405, 'Method Not Allowed'
url = "http://mockpublish.appspot.com/publish/api/revision_screen_create"
_, host, selector, _, _ = urllib2.urlparse.urlsplit(url)
print host, selector
h = httplib.HTTP(host)

h.putrequest('POST', selector)

BOUNDARY = '----------THE_FORM_BOUNDARY'
content_type = 'multipart/form-data; boundary=%s' % BOUNDARY
h.putheader('content-type', content_type)
h.putheader('User-Agent', 'Python-urllib/2.5,gzip(gfe)')
content = ""
L = []
L.append('--' + BOUNDARY)
L.append('Content-Disposition: form-data; name="test"')
L.append('')
L.append("xxx")
L.append('--' + BOUNDARY + '--')
L.append('')
content = '\r\n'.join(L)
h.putheader('content-length', str(len(content)))
h.endheaders()
h.send(content)

print h.getreply()

# post using urllib2 works
data = urllib.urlencode({'test':'xxx'})
request = urllib2.Request(url)
f = urllib2.urlopen(request, data)
output = f.read()
print output
```

Edit: After changing putrequest to request (on Nick Johnson's suggestion), it works

```
url = "http://mockpublish.appspot.com/publish/api/revision_screen_create"
_, host, selector, _, _ = urllib2.urlparse.urlsplit(url)

h = httplib.HTTPConnection(host)

BOUNDARY = '----------THE_FORM_BOUNDARY'
content_type = 'multipart/form-data; boundary=%s' % BOUNDARY

content = ""
L = []
L.append('--' + BOUNDARY)
L.append('Content-Disposition: form-data; name="test"')
L.append('')
L.append("xxx")
L.append('--' + BOUNDARY + '--')
L.append('')
content = '\r\n'.join(L)
h.request('POST', selector, content,{'content-type':content_type})
res = h.getresponse()
print res.status, res.reason, res.read()
```

so now the question remains what is the difference between two approaches and can first first be made to work?

Comment: Have you tried sending the request with httplib using .request() instead of .putrequest() etc, supplying the headers as a dict?

Comment: actually I wanted to send a file using multi-part form data, can i do that using request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Nick Johnson's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12030/nick-johnson) answer

Have you tried sending the request with httplib using .request() instead of .putrequest() etc, supplying the headers as a dict?

it works!